# Cropping an image using php

Tags: php, image, crop

I'm trying to crop an image when it has been uploaded. So far I've only managed to resize it but if an image is a rectangular shape then the image is squashed which doesn't look nice. I'm trying to get coding that I can use with the function that I currently have to resize. The ones that I'm seeing I have to change my function and I'm hoping not to do that.

Here is my function

```
function createThumbnail($filename) {
     global $_SITE_FOLDER;
    //require 'config.php';
    $final_width_of_image = 82;
    $height = 85;
    $path_to_image_directory = $_SITE_FOLDER.'portfolio_images/';
    $path_to_thumbs_directory = $_SITE_FOLDER.'portfolio_images/thumbs/';

    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    }

    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);

    $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));
    //$ny = $height;

    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);



    if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
      if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
           die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
      } 
       }

    imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);
    $tn = '<img src="' . $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename . '" alt="image" />';
    $tn .= '<br />Congratulations. Your file has been successfully uploaded, and a      thumbnail has been created.';
    echo $tn;
}
```

Comment: lately I started thinking that using already existent libraries to do specific work saved me time. Do you know of imagemagick? your web host might have to install it on your server so that you can use it but give it a look http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function.

```
 <?php
    function crop($file_input, $file_output, $crop = 'square',$percent = false) {
        list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
        if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {
            echo 'Unable to get the length and width of the image';
            return;
            }
            $types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');
            $ext = $types[$type];
            if ($ext) {
                    $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
                    $img = $func($file_input);
            } else {
                    echo 'Incorrect file format';
            return;
            }
        if ($crop == 'square') {
            $min = $w_i;
            if ($w_i > $h_i) $min = $h_i;
            $w_o = $h_o = $min;
        } else {
            list($x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o) = $crop;
            if ($percent) {
                $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
                $h_o *= $h_i / 100;
                $x_o *= $w_i / 100;
                $y_o *= $h_i / 100;
            }
                    if ($w_o < 0) $w_o += $w_i;
                $w_o -= $x_o;
            if ($h_o < 0) $h_o += $h_i;
            $h_o -= $y_o;
        }
        $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
        imagecopy($img_o, $img, 0, 0, $x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o);
        if ($type == 2) {
            return imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
        } else {
            $func = 'image'.$ext;
            return $func($img_o,$file_output);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And you can call like this

```
crop($file_input, $file_output, $crop = 'square',$percent = false);
```

And also resize function if you need.

```
<?php
function resize($file_input, $file_output, $w_o, $h_o, $percent = false) {
    list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
    if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {
        return;
        }
        $types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');
        $ext = $types[$type];
        if ($ext) {
                $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
                $img = $func($file_input);
        } else {
        return;
        }
    if ($percent) {
        $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
        $h_o *= $h_i / 100;
    }
    if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o/($w_i/$h_i);
    if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o/($h_i/$w_i);

    $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
    imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i);
    if ($type == 2) {
        return imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
    } else {
        $func = 'image'.$ext;
        return $func($img_o,$file_output);
    }
}
?>

resize($file_input, $file_output, $w_o, $h_o, $percent = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleImage class found here [SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage)

[edit] Updated version with many more features here [SimleImage Updated](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage/blob/master/src/abeautifulsite/SimpleImage.php)

I use this when resizing various images to a smaller thumbnail size while maintaining aspect ratio and exact image size output. I fill the blank area with a colour that suits the background for where the image will be placed, this class supports cropping. Explore the methods cutFromCenter and maxareafill.

For example in your code you would not need to `imagecreatefromjpeg()` you would simply;

Include the class `include('SimpleImage.php');`

then;

```
$im = new SimpleImage();
$im->load($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
$im->maxareafill($output_width,$output_height, 0,0,0); // rgb
$im->save($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
```

I use this class daily and find it very versatile.